# No such table SQLException

Tags: android

I have created a database using SQLite. Now I want to insert data to that table using an Android application.

I have written all this code in SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
try
        {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(key_id, 10);
        values.put(key_name,"neha");

        db.insert(database_table, null, values);
        db.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);          
        }
```

and then run the application. It throws no such table exception.

I have followed `"data/data/[your_package_name]/databases/"` then `"pull a file from device"` all these steps, but the database doesn't get on emulator.

What is the problem?

Comment: there is no table created in your database.

Comment: can you show the full code for creating database, table and for insertion..

Comment: Check the creation query of DB. There must be glitch there. For reference : http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: no such table in databse..create like in ur SQLiteOpenHelper class ...     @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

  db.execSQL(createTableQuery);

 }

Comment: try push a file onto device, and not pull a file

Answer (score 2):

I think you are new to android. Its good if you read some developer tutorials and start coding. For current application

1st: Create a separate class for database (for ex: HandleDatabase.java)

2nd:Create a helper class(with extending SQLiteOpenHelper) inside this to write onCreate(for creating table) and onUpgrade(recreating table in version change) method.

3rd: Create constructure for the HandleDatabase class with the current context.

4td: Write all CUID methods in the HandleDatabase  class.

EX:

```
//1st STEP
public class HandleDatabase {
private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "_name";
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "_myrnddb";
public static final String YOUR_TABLE = "_table";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
private DbHelper ourHelper;

       //2nd STEP
        public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createtableQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + YOUR_TABLE + " ("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

            db.execSQL(createtableQuery);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)   {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + YOUR_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

        }
    }
   //3rd STEP
   public HandleDatabase(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;
    }

    public HandleDatabase open() throws SQLException {
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
    }

    public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();
    }

    //Insertion(4th STEP)
    public long insertData(String name)
        throws SQLException {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME , name);
    return ourDatabase.insert(YOUR_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

 }
```

Like this you can select, update and delete data from your database.

To learn something about SQLite database you can follow [SQLite Tutorials](http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html)

Comment: so I have send some suggestions with an example.try in this way.

Comment: Yes u r right,i m new to android development,this is my first database connectivity application.i have one more query,android application itself create database when we call onCreate() method,or we want to create it manually with the help of sqlite prompt ?

Comment: SQLite is embedded into every Android device.You only have to define the SQL statements for creating and updating the database. Afterwards the database is automatically managed for you by the Android platform.check this link http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#SQLite in Android

Comment: if my answer helped you then its good if you accept.So it can help so many new developers in future.